# Adaptive bitrate streaming

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, video-processing, adaptive-bitrate

I'm newbie of video streaming. I have a question of adaptive bitrate streaming that i can't find the answer on net. I have 100+ videos and each of them have 3 different qualities: 360p, 720p and 1080p. Which mean i need 300+ videos store on my server.

If i use adaptive bitrate streaming solution like Wowza, do i still need to store 3 qualities  of each on my server? Or i just need the most quality video file(1080p) to store on server and Wowza will extract all qualities by itself to viewers?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert videos to all required different qualities like 360p, 720p etc., using a Transcoder (For example : [AWS Transcoder](http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/)) and then you need to keep all the different bitrate files in wowza server for adaptive bitrate streaming.

The below helps you to setup Adaptive Bitrate streaming in Wowza Server

[http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?546-How-to-do-adaptive-bitrate-streaming document to setup adaptive bitrate streaming](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?546-How-to-do-adaptive-bitrate-streaming)

Comment: Do you mean I still need to store 3 different qualities files not just 1 most high quality file?

Answer (score 1):

In Flash Media Servers (not just in Wowza, FWIW), the three are streamed on three different endpoints, either the client or the server has to implement an algorithm to detect bandwidth issues (normally by monitoring the playback queue length or jitter), and force the endpoint switch.